# A Question on Type Classes

Tags: scala, implicit, typeclass

I need to define a type class `Field` as follows:

```
trait Field[A] {  
  // Additive identity
  def zero: A

  // Multiplicative identity
  def one: A
}
```

The `Numeric` type class also provides the methods, `zero` and `one`.

I want that every class for which a `Numeric` instance is available can be used wherever a class with `Field` instance is required. For example, the following should work:

```
def func[F: Field](f: F) = println(f)
func(2)
```

Can you please suggest how to achieve this? I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
scala> implicit def numericToField[N](n: Numeric[N]) = new Field[N] {
     |     def zero = n.zero
     |     def one = n.one
     |   }
numericToField: [N](n: Numeric[N])java.lang.Object with Field[N]

scala> def func[F: Field](f: F) = println(f)
func: [F](f: F)(implicit evidence$1: Field[F])Unit

scala> func(2)
<console>:12: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Field[Int]
       func(2)
           ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've almost got it. You just need to make this small change:

```
scala> implicit def numericToField[N](implicit n: Numeric[N]) = new Field[N] {
 |     def zero = n.zero
 |     def one = n.one
 |   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is very nearly correct, but you should have defined func like so:

```
def func[F <% Field](f:F) = println(f)
```

As you defined it now, F must be a Field (or a subtype of Field), not just be convertible to one. The "F <% Field" notation means that all values that have an implicit conversion to Fields are also admissible. The second solution would also have worked if you had created an implicit Field[Int] instance somewhere in scope from the call to func(2).